# C# using a function from C++ dll with std::vector as parameter

Tags: c#, c++, stdvector

I have a C++ dll in which one of the functions takes an `std::vector<UInt16>` as a parameter. I want to use this API in a C# application but I am not sure if that is possible.

My C++ function :

```
EXPORT_API void STACKMODE ConfigurationStream(InterfaceManager * inst, std::vector<UInt16> address, std::vector <UInt16> data);
```

Is there some way to send a List or an array from C# or should I just change my API call to have two arrays with an extra `int` parameter as the size of the arrays. Note that both vectors will always have the same size.

Comment: You can only call methods with c parameter types from c#

Comment: *I have a C++ dll in which one of the functions takes an std::vector<UInt16> as a parameter* -- Note that even within C++, it would not be easy to use such a function.  You would have to ensure that whoever calls that function uses the exact same `std::vector` implementation, same compiler, same compiler settings, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it directly because there is nothing in the dotnet framework which has the exact memory layout of std::vector.
But your could do it if you would change your API to (as you asked in you question):

```
EXPORT_API void STACKMODE ConfigurationStream(
    InterfaceManager * inst
   , uint16_t* addressPtr
   , uint16_t* dataPtr
   , int32_t  cnt
);
```

Comment: This is fundamentally different in that it provides the `ConfigurationStream` function with read/write access to the caller's `address` and `data` data, whereas in the OP's C++ version the function receives its own deep copies of the vectors passed in.  That might be deliberate if e.g. `ConfigurationStream` needed to modify (e.g. sort/filter) the address/data without changing the caller's version, but it's a common oversight for beginning C++ programmers too.  If a deep copy is not needed, the function arguments should be `const std::vector<uint16_t>&`s.

Comment: Good point - do you wanted really a copy? I don't think so. A direct copy would not be possible because std::vector is just a wrapper around a dynamic array... To copy it needs to do a heap allocation...